# What is the genre of fantasy novels that don't feature any major conflict?

Tags: story-identification, novel, fantasy-genre, literary-analysis

When reading a fantasy novel I enjoy the chapters focusing on "normal" life in the fantastical world much more than chapters focusing on a quest to defeat some existential threat. For example:

- I enjoyed the first part of "The Wheel of Time" when the main characters are living life in the village and then travelling together without really understanding the threat that they'll eventually face much more than the later parts detailing their conflict with "The Dark One"; and
- I enjoyed the parts of "Harry Potter" that focused on school life and relationships much more than the parts that focused on the conflict with "He Who Must Not Be Named".

However, I'm finding it hard to find these types of fantasy novels set in a world where there isn't any existential threat that needs to be defeated and the story is instead driven by less epic concerns and relationships. Is there a named genre or any common way to refer to these sorts of novels?

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for? General reading recommendations that don't have a definitive answer are off-topic here. (That said, you seem to be looking for "slice of life" stories. Try searching with that phrase)

Comment: I'm not going to post these as answers, since this will be closed as off topic, but here are a few classic fantasy novels that have important slice-of-life elements, with rather less conflict driving the plots:  *The King of Elfland's Daughter*, *Gulliver's Travels*, *Erewhon*.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the question, so that it's no longer asking for reading recommendations, but I'll be sure to check out the books you've mentioned!

Comment: @MJD Could you take look at the edited question and let me know if you still think it's off-topic?

Comment: VTR. The query is now asking for the name of a genre, not a reading list.

Comment: Unfortunately our [current meta policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/how-about-revisiting-our-policy-about-is-there-any-questions-being-ok) on "are/is there any" questions means this question is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure there really is a genre like that -- generally a story needs a definitive plot, not just descriptions of everyday life in some world, interesting though that may be.  You might, however, like Katherine Kurtz's Deryni novels; there are conflicts that make the plot interesting/suspenseful (some books more, some less), but less 'epic' in proportion (the whole world isn't usually about to be destroyed or something like that) and it is very people-focused.  And, she is an historian, and the books are written a bit like a history of a fictional world.

Comment: One such genre would be "travelogue"

Comment: Travelogue is one good possibility. Slice of life, plotless narrative, quotidian fiction are other possibles.

Comment: @fez Could you give me a link to the policy? I tried to find a list of what is in-topic for scifi, but I couldn't locate it.

Comment: The [tour] has examples of questions to ask vs questions not to ask. You can also have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). The links to those pages (and more) is found in the [help]

Comment: Thanks. I've read those links, but I still can't understand why this question is off-topic.

Comment: @andypea I'm not a close-voter (not enough rep either way), but my guess is it's a combination of "reading recommendation" and "genre classification", both of which are off-topic. I think you've made improvements in shifting the discussion to story elements, but sometimes it takes a better question to be reopened than to not be closed in the first place.

Comment: I've occasionally seen the word "Cozy" used in association with another genre, although the most common version seems to be "cosy catastrophe" where an apocalypse is used as an excuse to present a new world, but no one seems to have any real problems with securing supplies.